# validated symfony1 password hash

Tags: php, hash, passwords, symfony1

I am rewriting application build on symphony 1.4.0, i want to reuse the users passwords but my problem is that i don't know anything about symfony and how it is creating the password hashes.Can someone points me in the right direction ?

Comment: You might try the symfony IRC channel: http://symfony.com/irc or look through the code: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/lib/model/doctrine/PluginsfGuardUser.class.php#L42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you i did found out, its static salt in app.yml file and the password hashed with sha1

Comment: Then you need to upgrade those; if need be, wrap a new algorithm around the existing peppered SHA1 hash (label those version 1 password hashes in the DB), and use just the new algorithm for new ones and for everyone that logs in again (label those version 2 password hashes).  See [Thomas Pornin's canonical answer to How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/39623) - choose PBKDF2 with hundreds of thousands of iterations (tens of thousands minimum), and get no more than the native hash size output bytes, or BCrypt/Scrypt with a high work factor.

Comment: Also, a static salt is usually known as a "pepper"; salts are specifically per-user, cryptographically randomly generated.